# Calculating User Score Based on Elapsed Seconds

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have a simple quiz game, which calculates user's score by using score = 100 - ((100*answerTime)/60); formula.

When I display user's score on the screen with a timer, it displays it like
100, 99, 97...

Is there a way to display this score smoother to the user? Like 100, 99, 98 I've searched it on the web but the closest answer i came up was a bézier curve algorithm which was for a flash animation.

Below is the sample code:

```
private function TimerHandler(e:TimerEvent):void
    {
        var ticks:int = e.target.currentCount;
        var score:int = CalculateScore(ticks);
        trace("Elapsed time: " + ticks + ", score: " + score);

        if(ticks == 59)
        {
            trace("Time out! User got 0 points on this question");
            e.target.stop();
        }
    }

private function CalculateScore(answerTime:uint):int
{
    return 100 - ((100*answerTime)/60);
}
```

and in constructor:

```
var tmr:Timer = new Timer(1000);
tmr.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,TimerHandler);
tmr.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you must discount 100 points in 59 lapses then each lap must discount more than 1 point. My suggestion is to set the timer in 600ms then you will be 100 lapses in a minute.

Comment: But if i set timer in 600ms, my score starts to get negative values. I want to keep score as it is. Score must be discount from 100 points in one minute, but my display should show it like it's decreasing by 1 each second. I guess I didn't understand your suggestion though. :)